# Фреймоврки и шаблонизаторы

Tags: framework, php, шаблонизаторы, kohana, smarty

Я знаю, что самым более-менее сносным фреймворком считается сейчас kohana. Пытаясь что-то свое написать, используя MVC, я столкнулся с проблемой вывода данных из контроллера в вид. Копаясь на форумах, мне сказали, что для этой цели лучше использовать smarty-шаблонизатор или YII. Теперь не знаю, как быть и что учить, smarty - штука староватая, там даже (только что пробовал запустить) конструктор по старому пишется. Все-таки "что" есть "что", фреймворк - это фреймворк, а шаблонизатор - это шаблонизатор? Или по сути это одно и тоже и учить лучше kohana?

Comment: Стесняюсь спросить - на кой вам шаблонизатор?.. С какой целью вы собираетесь его использовать? Если потому, что кто-то вам так сказал - не стоит. PHP сам по себе является отличным шаблонизатором.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как всё сумбурно-то=) А с какой именно проблемой вывода данных из контроллера в вид Вы столкнулись? И как вообще вышли на smarty?

Kohana использовать стоит. Я Вам как проверенный боец это говорю. Приятный фреймворк. Удобная реализация HMVC + кучу написанных модулей можно на гитхабе найти. Документация написана понятно, даже с туториалами вроде.

Вот пара строк из документации как раз по Вашей проблеме передачи параметров в отображение

```
// In your controller:

public functin action_index()
{
    $view = View::factory('common/template');

    $view->title = "Some title";
    $view->body = View::factory('pages/foobar');
}

// In views/common/template.php:

<html>
<head>
    <title><?php echo $title></title>
</head>

<body>
    <?php echo $body ?>
</body>
</html>
```

[Источник](http://kohanaframework.org/3.2/guide/kohana/mvc/views)

Answer (score 0):

Фреймворк - это готовая сборка классов, повседневно использующихся в разработке. Там есть всё необходимое для быстрого старта. Также это всё оформленно в виде паттерна MVC (Модель - Контроллер - Вид).

Контроллер всем управляет, модель отвечает за поведение данных, а вид - это как раз и есть шаблонизатор.

Посмотри видео уроки Морковина по Kohana, многое станет ясно.